# json file missing Brackets

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, json, next.js

json format test with postman

```
{
    "localTimeStamp": "2021-08-14T08:19:17.000Z",
    "ipAddress": "10.0.5.26",
    "subnetMask": "N/A",
    "defaultGateway": "N/A",
    "productType": "UNIVERGE BX9000",
    "versionID": "7.20A.256.721",
    "protocolType": "SIP",
    "operationalState": "UNLOCKED",
    "highAvailability": "Not Operational",
    "serialNumber": "9107130",
    "macAddress": "00908f8af6ba",
    "systemUpTime": 4049040,
    "saveNeeded": false,
    "resetNeeded": false
}
```

i use this code in nex.js to fetch the info

```
import styles from '../styles/Jobs.module.css'

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/status',{
    headers: { Authorization: "Basic passsssworrdssss" }
  }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
 
  return {
    props: { ninjas: data }
    
  }
}

const Ninjas = ({ ninjas }) => {
  console.log(ninjas)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All Ninjas</h1>
      {ninjas.map(ninja => (
        <div key={ninja.id}>
          <a className={styles.single}>
            <h3>{ ninja.productType }</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Ninjas;
```

the error is browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqgVV.png)

think the problem is The .map function is only available on array.
It looks like data isn't in the format you are expecting it to be (it is {} but im expecting []).

hopefully someone knows the solution to solve the error

output of console.log(ninjas) looks ok now
only got still error in browser

ReferenceError: ninja is not defined

```
[
  {
    localTimeStamp: '2021-08-14T10:30:35.000Z',
    ipAddress: '10.0.5.26',
    subnetMask: 'N/A',
    defaultGateway: 'N/A',
    productType: 'UNIVERGE BX9000',
    versionID: '7.20A.256.721',
    protocolType: 'SIP',
    operationalState: 'UNLOCKED',
    highAvailability: 'Not Operational',
    serialNumber: '9107130',
    macAddress: '00908f8af6ba',
    systemUpTime: 4056919,
    saveNeeded: false,
    resetNeeded: false
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the output of the ```console.log(ninjas)```  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
props: { ninjas: data }
```

Here, according to your description, `data` is given as

```
{ "localTimeStamp": "2021-08-14T08:19:17.000Z" ...}
```

So `ninjas` is not an array, it's a normal object now.

`ninjas.map` requires ninjas to be an array and as it is not, an error occured.

To fix it, you can fix this part.

```
props: { ninjas: [data]}
```

Comment: got a different error when i change the props: { ninjas: [data]}     error= ReferenceError: ninja is not defined

Answer (score 2):

**It's an object so you don't need to loop through it to get the value insides:**

Just direct access them like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>All Ninjas</h1>
    <div key={ninja.id}>
        <a className={styles.single}>
          <h3>{ ninja.productType }</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**- Be aware that `id` is not available in your object so `ninja.id` is invalid which return an undefined**

**- Consider using `getServerSideProps` to fetch data on each request. Because `getStaticProps` fetch data at build time**

Comment: @clones Look like you are trying to edit my answer while you want to give a comment. Please post another question so everyone can have a better focus on that issue.

Comment: new error  ReferenceError: ninja is not defined

Comment: ouput console.log(ninjas)

Comment: `getStaticProps` is to fetch data at build time. Change to `getServerSideProps` instead. That will fetch data on each request.